# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #1](https://poker.stackexchange.com/election/1) on Poker has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Grinch91]

[image: Jon]

[image: Toby Booth]

Toby and Grinch91 will retain their diamonds after serving as pro-tem mods, and Jon will be joining [them](https://poker.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking the following user, who will be stepping down as moderator after serving as a pro-tem moderator:

[image: Radu Murzea]

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://poker.stackexchange.com/election/1) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5331621554159616).

Comment: Congrats to all the winners, and thanks to Radu for your work as a pro-tem mod!

Comment: Thanks Radu, and congrats to Toby and Jon too!